# SVN Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 5000) with output

Tags: svn, out-of-memory, pre-commit-hook

I copied a directory (tags) from main repo to a test branch using svn copy. Now, I can't commit anything toward the tags I just copied over (including deleting it), which isn't important, but I also need to copy trunk over to the test branch, and it's giving me the commit blocked error.

Now, I'm trying to delete the tags directory but it's not letting me. Deleting every single directory and file inside each tag works, but delete the tag_name or tags directory gives the same error. Also, deleting directories in the same level as tags directory works.

The log states reason is due to "System.OutOfMemoryException".
The closest explanation I could get is this:

> if the commit dialog is left open on a big working copy and other apps/tools modify the files inside that working copy, the path watcher stores each and every modified file in memory until it can not reserve enough memory. The path watcher is necessary to check whether a commit can be done recursively or not.
>   To avoid memory exceptions, only store a limited amount of paths. If the limit is reached, automatically fall back to a non-recursive commit.

Is there anyway for me to delete this directory now?

EDIT: I am now certain that this isn't a pre-commit hook error. I cannot create tags anymore in the main repo. However, I'm able to create a tag ONCE every time I restart SVN server. Exact same commit done. It is extremely annoying to have to restart SVN everyday. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The summary of the question is:

> SVN Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 5000) with output

The error means that the [pre-commit hook script](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html) you use rejects the commit. Check the hook script on the server.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense. I've copy individual trunk and tag and then deleting them numerous time already. It only happened after I copied the whole tags directory over. To make sure, I did ask the administrator and he says there're no pre-commit hooks.